# Recursive Complete Binary Tree in Python - The tree is skewed

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Here is a recursive implementation of a Complete Binary tree( Not a Binary Search Tree in Python from a list. Need help with the logic to build the balanced tree, the logic i have written generates a skewed tree. I am aware it can be done with Queues but I need a recursive implementation.

Here is the code:

```
class Node:
    """A simple Binary Node to be used in a Tree"""

    def __init__(self, value=-1, leftNode=None, rightNode=None):
        self.value = value
        self.leftNode = leftNode
        self.rightNode = rightNode

class BinaryTree:
def __init__(self, root=None):
    self.root = root
    self.noOfLeftNodes = 0
    self.noOfRightNodes = 0

def addNode(self, root, node):
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = node
        return
    if root.leftNode is None:
        root.leftNode = node
        self.noOfLeftNodes += 1
        return
    elif root.rightNode is None:
        root.rightNode = node
        self.noOfRightNodes += 1
        return

    else:
        if self.noOfLeftNodes - self.noOfRightNodes < 2:
            self.addNode(root.leftNode, node)
        else:
            self.addNode(root.rightNode, node)

def preorder(self, root):
    if root is None:
        return
    print(root.value)
    self.preorder(root.leftNode)
    self.preorder(root.rightNode)

#Test stub 
    bt = BinaryTree()
    nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    for i in range(len(nodes)):
        bt.addNode(bt.root, Node(nodes[i]))
    print('---Binary Tee---')
    bt.preorder(bt.root)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what happens, when your algorithm runs:

- 1 becomes the root. (#left = 0, #right = 0).
- 2 becomes the left child of the root (#left = 1, #right = 0).
- 3 becomes the right child of the root (#left = 1, #right = 1).
- 4 triggers the `else` and because #left - #right = 0 < 2, it is inserted ...
- ... (Do that, until you get to a point where the algorithm does not what you expect.)

**Hint:** #left and #right *not* are doing what they should. If you insert something as a left child in the right subtree of the root, #left is incremented. Try to maintain these values for each node, not just once for the whole tree.

Comment: Extract the root. Build the left subtree out of the left half of the remaining list, and tge right subtree out of the right half of the same. If the number of nodes is not exactly right, you need to divide unevenly.